# What kind of stats would you like to see from challenges?

Tags: discussion, challenge

Recent meta posts have brought up the idea that results for the topic challenges should show some stats.

Since many of our challenge posts are now [automatically generated](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/challenge), and since I'm the author of that generator, I need to know what to include in the posts.

So, two questions for you:

1. What stats would you like to see included in the results posts?
2. Should the results be sorted by any of these stats?

You can take a look at the [API docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs), if you're so minded, to see what kind of data I can actually get.

Answer (score 6):

It would be nice to see something like:

> (question title) (total score of Q + As) (number of answers)

And maybe sort by the total score.  This gives us a very rough measure of community response -- it's a rough measure of how *we* responded to it.  This is distinct from other possibly-interesting data like view counts, which are broader.  Everybody who follows a link from a tweet or HNQ or the like contributes to the views, but only people with accounts (and at least 15 rep) can actually vote.

Comment: I agree and would also be interested to see number of views as well, although I suspect this is mathematically related to the number who have taken part.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how useful this would be to anyone else, but I would like to know the impact the challenge had on that tag. For instance, if you could grab something as simple as how many questions used the tag before the challenge, and compare it to the number of questions asked during the challenge. And, if you can do that, it's probably not too hard to compare vote counts or average number of answers.

But like I said, I don't know if anyone other than me would care about it.

Comment: I would find that interesting. Incidentally, I'd be interested to see how introducing the *other* stats would affect this proposed stat! We could actually (one-off) measure whether people were more motivated to take up a challenge if they also know they will see the stats on it.